# EASTL versus STL, how can there be such a performance difference in std::vector<uint64_t>::operator[]

Tags: c++, optimization, stl, eastl

According to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html
`vector<uint64>::operator[]` is between 2% and 70% faster in EASTL than a "commonly used commercial version of STL".

Unless the commercial version of STL uses range checking, which would make the comparison unfair, how can it possibly be such a speed difference for such a simple operation?

*Update:*

Seems the answer is that the EA engineers is simply cheating by comparing with a version which uses range checking...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The document states that they used VC++ 2005 for Windows testing, with which [checked iterators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965%28VS.80%29.aspx) are [enabled by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985896%28VS.80%29.aspx) (yes, even for release builds; same goes for VC++ 2008). I suspect that the performance of `operator[]` wouldn't be any different if they added `-D_SECURE_SCL=0` to their build command-line.

Comment: wouldn't make a difference as `vector<...>::operator[]` is implemented as `{return (*(this->_Myfirst + _Pos));}` i.e no iterators involved.

Comment: @Viktor Sehr : That's the code that's executed when `_SECURE_SCL` is `#define`d to `0`. When `_SECURE_SCL` = `1`, as is the default, substantially different code is run. (Also note that the STL implementation in VC++ 2010 is vastly different than that in VC++ 2005 and 2008, so looking at 2010's implementation is not relevant here.)

Comment: @bruce.banner : In VC++ 2010, checked iterators are disabled by default for release builds. I.e., they're still available, but you have to enable them manually.

Answer (score 4):

I think this passage from the documentation will be crucial

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html#eastl_allocator

It is apparently inspired by the famous 'Towards a better allocator model' article by Pablo Halpern

Comment: How would a better allocator affect `operator[]`?

Comment: Apparently their allocator takes into consideration alignment requirements and this could make access to specific locations a lot faster using specific access patterns. However, AFAICT their precise benchmark method is not published (on the same page)